# How do I add a code to auto-delete extra sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of @clomee , many many thanks, I currently have this code.
It allows me to input a certain number in the cell and it will copy my template Window sheet so I can input individual sizes and specs for each one in each sheet.

This code below allows me to input let's say 6no, and by changing that to 8 later, it will only copy the template 2x more times instead of adding 8 extra copies.

I need to somehow add another function to it, so if I replace "8" in the cell with 5, it will count backwards and delete all sheets that have numbers >5 in their name.

It's probably easy code, but it's thanks to the help and answers I got here I managed to get this far and streamline what I started with to begin with.

Thank you so much!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Excel.Range)
    If target.Cells.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(target) And target.Address = "$B$4" Then
        Select Case target.Value
            Case 1 To 50: copierW
            End Select
            End If
End Sub
Sub copierW()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, x As Integer
Set sh1 = Sheets("Main")
Set sh2 = Sheets("W-Template")
Set wh = Sheets("Reference")
x = ActiveSheet.Range("b4")
Count = 0
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If Left(sh.Name, 1) = "W" And Right(sh.Name, 1) = "." Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next sh
needed_copies = x - Count
    For numtimes = 1 To needed_copies
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("W-Template").Copy _
        After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
        Count2 = Count + numtimes
        ActiveSheet.Name = "W" & Count2 & "."
    Next
Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folowing code deletes all sheets which contain a higher number after the "W" as the value of x.

```
Sub copierW()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, x As Integer
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("W-Template")
Set wh = Sheets("Reference")
x = sh1.Cells(4, 2).Value
count = 0
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If Left(sh.Name, 1) = "W" And Right(sh.Name, 1) = "." Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next sh
needed_copies = x - count
If needed_copies < 0 Then
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If Left(sh.Name, 1) = "W" And Right(sh.Name, 1) = "." And x < Left(Right(sh.Name, Len(sh.Name) - 1), Len(sh.Name) - 2) Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sh.Name).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next sh
Else
    For numtimes = 1 To needed_copies
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("W-Template").Copy _
        After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
        Count2 = count + numtimes
        ActiveSheet.Name = "W" & Count2 & "."
    Next
End If
Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Clomee!
You've been such a massive help over these past few days!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

I declared your undeclared variables and changed `x` to a long (don't use integer).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Excel.Range)
    If target.Cells.count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(target) And target.Address = "$B$4" Then
        Select Case target.Value
            Case 1 To 50: copierW
            End Select
            End If
End Sub
Sub copierW()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, wh As Worksheet, x As Long
Dim count As Long, needed_copies As Long, numtimes As Long, count2 As Long
Set sh1 = Sheets("Main")
Set sh2 = Sheets("W-Template")
Set wh = Sheets("Reference")
x = ActiveSheet.Range("b4")
count = 0
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If Left(sh.Name, 1) = "W" And Right(sh.Name, 1) = "." Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next sh
needed_copies = x - count
    If needed_copies < 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For Each sh In Worksheets
            If Left(sh.Name, 1) = "W" And Right(sh.Name, 1) = "." Then
                If Mid(sh.Name, 2, Len(sh.Name) - 1) > x Then
                    sh.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next sh
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        For numtimes = 1 To needed_copies
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("W-Template").Copy _
            After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
            count2 = count + numtimes
            ActiveSheet.Name = "W" & count2 & "."
        Next
    End If
Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub
```